# Emacs extension in VS2010 not available as keyboard layout option

Tags: visual-studio-2010, emacs

I'm setting up a new laptop and just installed VS2010 Professional. I downloaded and installed the emacs extension. It appears in the list of installed extensions, but when I select Tools->Options->Keyboard, it's not one of the choices. The webpage for the extension says that it should ask for admin privileges in order to install, but this doesn't happen. I removed the extension, started VS2010 in Run As Admin and tried again, with the same results.

I'm baffled - I made this work a couple of years ago on another machine, but not this time. No idea what I'm doing differently.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After updating everything and seeing no change, I tried one more idea - I loaded a solution. As the solution loaded, I got the dialog requesting elevated permissions. Go figure. Now I can select emacs as the keyboard bindings.